# How do I filter and print after groupBy?

Tags: pyspark

I have a DF where 1st column is a name and second is a department with at max 3 departments. I want to filter rows where a name is present in all three departments.

```
name, dept, ...
test, d1
test, d2
test, d3
test1, d1
test1, d3
```

So after transformation, I want to see the following:

```
test, d1
test, d2
test, d3
```

What I have tried so far is df.groupBy("name").show() which does not work because I am not doing any aggregation after groupBy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Join` and `groupby` in one job may result into more shuffles. Use window Functions to broadcast count of `dept` per `name` in a new column `count`. Select count==3 and drop the broacast column

```
w = Window.partitionBy('name')
df.withColumn('count',count('dept').over(w)).where(col('count')==3).drop('count').show()

+----+----+
|name|dept|
+----+----+
|test|  d1|
|test|  d2|
|test|  d3|
+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([('test', 'd1'), ('test', 'd2'), ('test', 'd3'), ('test1', 'd1'), ('test1', 'd3')], ["name", "dept"])
```

```
df1 = df.groupBy("name").agg(count("dept").alias("cnt")).filter(col("cnt")==3)
df2 = df.join(df1, "name").select(df["name"], df["dept"])
df2.show()
```

**Output :**

```
+----+----+
|name|dept|
+----+----+
|test|  d1|
|test|  d2|
|test|  d3|
+----+----+
```